# local TFX pipeline run create ERROR Failed to make stateful working dir ; Protocol error

Tags: pipeline, local, tfx

I am following Building a TFX Pipeline Locally (https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/build_local_pipeline) on ubuntu 21.04. I am only running the CsvExampleGen component and I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:absl:Failed to make stateful working dir: ./my_pipeline_output/CsvExampleGen/.system/stateful_working_dir/2022-01-05T11:04:16.463569
Traceback (most recent call last):........
File "/home/mc/anaconda3/envs/tfx_linux/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 514, in recursive_create_dir_v2
    _pywrap_file_io.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: ./my_pipeline_output/CsvExampleGen/.system/stateful_working_dir/2022-01-05T11:04:16.463569; Protocol error
```

Do any suggestions, please?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried executing the same code as per the guide or modified part of it? If you had modified, can you share the code to reproduce the error from our end and help you in trouble-shooting the same. Thanks!

Comment: We tried reproducing the code in our local environment and it worked fine. Can you try creating the directory manually to make sure that there aren't any reasons. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It helped me when I moved my project to somewhere else, like the desktop, I guess the path is too long to be able to create this directory.